# place the icon to the leftmost of the toolbar

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am new to ionic. i want to place icon to the left most of the toolbar.

I have used `slot="start" , class="float-right"` and `ion-float-right` inside the tag but nothing works.

```css
.logo{
    width:100%;
    height: 57px;
    float:  left !important;
}
```

```html
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-img class="logo float-left"  src='assets/dqlogo-edge.png'></ion-img>  
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>

</ion-content>
```

Comment: Can you please create stack blitz demo?

Answer (score 0):

Try placing your image within an `<ion-buttons>` element. According to the [Ionic docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/toolbar), this element is where the `slot` attribute should be used, like so:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-buttons slot="start">
      <ion-img class="logo"  src='assets/dqlogo-edge.png'></ion-img>  
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
```

Answer (score -1):

Assign below styles to your `class`.

```
.float-left{
  float:left;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```html
   <img  class="logo float-left"  src='../assets/dqlogo-edge.png'>
```

This worked for me.